# ActiveRecord: Using the average of a related model in a query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have some Rails models that look a bit like this:

```
class Manufacturer
  has_many :widgets
end

class Widget
  belongs_to :manufacturer
  has_many :listings

  def weighted_average
    listings.sum('value * stock') / listings.sum('stock')
  end
end

class Listing
  # Represents that a merchant is selling some widgets
  belongs_to :widget
  belongs_to :merchant
  # Model has a :price, eg. $5.99
  # Also has a :stock, eg. 45 units
end
```

I now want to find all `Listing` objects where `Listing#value` is below the `weighted_average` of the `Widget` it belongs to.

For example, if a particular widget has an average price of $5, and there are listings for $4, $4.50 and $6, I'd like to return the first two - as they're below the average price and represent a good deal.

The query should produce a list of all cheaply-priced listings for all widgets, and I'd like to be able to do this in a single query.

How can I do this using ActiveRecord queries? In ideal pseudocode, it'd be something like:

```
Listing.where('listing.price < widget.weighted_average')
# Not possible, because weighted_average isn't a column in the DB, but a method.
```

Comment: Have you tried: `Listing.where('price < ?', widget.weighted_average)` ?

Comment: What's `widgets.sum('value * stock') / widgets.sum('stock')`, or more precisely what's `widgets` here in `weighted_average ` method?

Comment: I want this to work for multiple widgets, not just the listings for a single widget. The suggestion above will use the same value for the `where` clause, not the average of the listing's widget. I also realised I meant to have `listings.sum`, not `widgets.sum` - I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Listing.joins(:widget).where("#{Listing.table_name}.price < ?", 15)
```

Edit:

Number has to be replaced with your weighted average function result. Depending on database you're using, it can be one sql query that returns exactly what you want. For instance, for PostgreSQL `HAVING` clause is needed.

Comment: I've updated my question to be a bit clearer - the query should produce a list of all cheaply-priced listings for all widgets, and I'd like to be able to do this in a single query. The number is dynamic and needs to be looked up in the query, rather than passing in a variable.

Comment: Take a look at `HAVING` clause then.